# Woocommerce add products to categories and subcategories programatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add an inventory to a woocomerce website. I currently have an array that looks like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Lenovo 0A36307 
        [product_id] => 0
        [type] => simple
        [description] => Technical Specifications:
                            Manufacturer:  Lenovo
                            Model: 0A36307
                            Model compatible Lenovo Thinkpad x220, x230
                            Excellent quality at better than new prices.
        [regular_price] => 119.99
        [old_price] => 50.00
        [manage_stock] => 1
        [stock] => 0
        [weight] => 0
        [has_variations] => 0
        [image] => [.......]/s/files/1/0016/1133/3750/products/batterie_20lenovo_200a36307_20x230_fin_c23370c7-1d32-4403-90ff-f4e27a9522f7.jpg
        [woo_cat_id] => 51
        [woo_cat] => Laptop
        [woo_sub_cat] => Lenovo
    )
[...]
```

[woo_cat_id] is equal to the terme_id in wp_terms (I asumed that was the categorie ID)

[image]

I started looping the above array to add the items. The code looks like this:

```
logger("Checking if ".$product['name']." exists or not");
$check_sku=get_product_by_sku($product['product_id']);

if (empty($check_sku) ){
  logger("Product does not exists proceed with insert");
  $item = [
    'post_title' => $product['name'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_content' => $product['description']
  ];
  $postId = wp_insert_post($item);
}else{
  logger("Product exists proceed with update");
  $id= $check_sku->get_id();
  $my_post = array(
    'ID' =>  $id,
    'post_title' => $product['name'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_content' => $product['description']
 );
 
 $postId = wp_update_post( $my_post );
}

logger("Creating product meta");

update_post_meta( $postId, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_stock_status', 'instock');
update_post_meta( $postId, '_regular_price', $product['regular_price'] );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_price', $product['regular_price'] );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_weight', $product['weight'] );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_sku', $product['product_id'] );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_stock', $product['stock'] );
update_post_meta( $postId, '_manage_stock', 'yes' );

logger("Adding product to category: ".$product['woo_cat']." (".$product['woo_cat_id'].")");

wp_set_object_terms( $postId, $product['woo_cat_id'], 'product_cat' );
```

The product is added but it somehow created a category using the [woo_cat_id] as the name instead of associating it to the existing category.

[image]

Also as you can see in the above picture, there's a subcategory for brands. How can I verify by name if the subcategory [woo_sub_cat] exists for the parent [woo_cat] and if not create it then associate it?

Am I wrong in using wp_set_object_terms()? or is there something else I can use?
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inetead of wp_set_object_terms, you could use:

```
$p = wc_get_product( $postId );
//set categories with setter method
$p->set_category_ids( [$product['woo_cat_id']] );
$p->save();
```